# Which iPad devices support 3 apps on screen at once in iOS 11?

Tags: ipad, ios

In iOS 11, three active apps can be on screen at once. Running the public beta on my iPad Air only shows one active app on screen at a time. I assume the new 2017 iPad Pro devices can show 3 active apps but can any other iPad do that?

Answer (score 1):

iPads with 2GB or more memory support split view and slide over (that is, running multiple apps up to 3 and a PIP video in iOS 11 at once). These device includes iPad Air 2, iPad Mini 4, and iPad Pro (all models). Older devices (in your case an iPad Air) doesn’t have that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough, my iPad Pro 12.9” (previous gen) supports split screen and slide over but does not allow 3 apps to be open at the same time (i.e., if I have 2 apps open side-by-side, when I slide another app over from the right, the two currently open apps grey out, and tapping them causes the slide over app to disappear once more). This is clearly unexpected from an iPad Pro, but it could also be only public beta 1. Nonetheless I will feedback if this pattern continues with the next beta update, as I shouldn’t be getting any less of an experience by upgrading to iOS 11 compared to other iPad Pros.

Comment: If you’re already in split view in iOS 11 you can drag another app out of the dock to open that on top of the two apps (allowing 3 to be opened at the same time)